# Java: How to get immediate parent(who is not the top level class) from an inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I'm aware the differences between static nested class and inner class in Java. 
I'm talking about inner class.
I'm also aware that we can use "OuterClass.this" to get the outer class from inner class.

Like directory, there are two ways to navigate: absolute and relative.
For example: "/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd", if I'm inside folder "ccc" and want to refer to "bbb", we can either: "cd /aaa/bbb" or "cd ..".

Now comes to Java inner classes.

```
class AAA{
    BBB b = new BBB();
    class BBB{
        CCC c = new CCC();
        //CCC c = new CCC(b);
        class CCC{
            //SECOND VERSION
            //BBB parent = null
            //CCC(BBB parent_){
            //    parent = parent_;
            //}
            DDD d = new DDD();
            BBB GetParent(){
                return AAA.this.b;    //I know this will work
                //or return parent; if using the SECOND VERSION
            }
            class DDD{
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

I've provided two versions:
AAA.this.b
and 
introduce a member variable "parent", assigned with the value from parameter of the constructor.

**My question:**
If I don't introduce a member variable, may I use relative way to get its immediate parent from inner class? (like cd ..)

Comment: How is AAA.this.b the "parent"?  It is not clear what you are asking for?  Both versions return an arbitrary instance of class BBB - not the one that contains the DDD object with the GetParent method.  So it seems to be a third version would be 'return new BBB();`

Comment: Thanks. But I can not agree. I thought this scenario is clear. If you have an instance of AAA, say "a", then you will have: a, a.b, a.b.c, a.b.c.d; You will have 4 instances assembled in the nested order.

Comment: Does BBB.this not work?

Comment: Obviously, you already have a means of getting to the instance of the parent in your getParent() class. That's the way to do it. It actually makes me wonder what you're asking. Why isn't getParent() suitable ?

You can also get the parent classes of inner classes through the `java.lang.Class` method, `getDeclaringClass()`

Comment: "BBB.this" is the answer I wanted. getParent is way I usually in C++; Since Java have "BBB.this", I don't have to implement a function like "getParent" for each level of the declaration of inner classes (nor define the extra "m_Parent" variable). Thank you for all your efforts and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BBB.this` to directly refer to the enclosing instance of class BBB.

Answer (score 0):

Although normally the inner class code doesn't need a reference to
the outer class, since it already has an implicit one it's using to access the members
of the outer class, it would need a reference to the outer class if it needed to pass that
reference to some other code. If that's what yo want, just use the first version.